# Translation of ETL process

Tags: translation

I am working as an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) designer and developer constructing complex ETL processes.

I need to write resume in German and I don’t know whether ETL needs to be translated and if yes, what translation will be.

Comment: It would help if you would tell us which ETL you mean, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETL) lists several uses for this abbreviation. You can also use the [German wikipedia page](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETL) to verify if an abbreviation with this meaning also exists in German.

Comment: ETL means Extract, Transform and Load, but is known as ETL process. Whatever, your link helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to translate ETL into German, it's a well known term. Even the German Wikipedia page is called [ETL-Prozess](http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETL-Prozess) (with a *Bindestrich*, of course).